# Meaning of the phrase "don't judge a book by its cover?"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I am struggling to understand this phrase. It sounds like it's saying that you shouldn't judge someone by the way they look or are the first time you meet them. But in real life, once you get to know someone, they are always more rotten on the inside than you thought when you first met them. Usually, we have rose-colored glasses on when we meet someone new, not an instinct to judge negatively. So we are more likely to not judge them at first anyways, only to be blindsided by all their inner trauma and wounds and selfishness the more we get to know them. So shouldn't the phrase be instead: "make sure to judge a book by its cover, or else."

Comment: 'It sounds like it's saying that you shouldn't judge someone by the way they look or are the first time you meet them.' That is exactly what it means. Your question appears to be a complaint about the illogicality of the proverb, which, although understandable, is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to complaining about a proverb.

Comment: "they are always more rotten on the inside than you thought" That's your personal experience, it's not a given that everyone feels the same.

Comment: '... seems to **be** complaining about a proverb', I should have typed. I often judge books by their covers. if I am in a bookshop, looking for a spy thriller, and I pick up a book, and see on the cover, 'An illustrated guide to turnip farming', I know I won't enjoy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding of the meaning of the proverb is correct.

Your point appears to be that you don't agree with the idea behind the proverb. Sure, we can debate whether the proverb is good advice or not. But the meaning is exactly what you say. Whether or not that's good advice is a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, since it can go both ways:

1. You may decide to not judge a person but they turn out to be rotten (the example you've given)

But why can't the opposite also be true?
It can also mean:

2. At first glance you dislike or judge a person, but later come to realise that they're in fact, better than you thought?

Not everyone looks through rose-coloured glasses at all times, and this way, it is true in both cases instead of the one you've suggested, which would only be true for one case.